# Checking membership status and loggin in

Tags: php, mysqli

Can somebody push me in right direction and tell what is wrong with this code. I am not receiving any errors however it is not logging me in either.
The idea was to have a row called memb in the sql database and check if the status is 1 or 0. If it is 1, it would take you to the secured page and if 0 it would give you the subscibing page

```
<?php


require_once('config.php');  


if(isset($_POST['Login']) && isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pass1'])) {
// Here check if all input are sent 

$uname = $sql-> real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$pass1 = $sql-> real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);


 if ( !empty($uname) && !empty($pass1)) {
  // Check if you input are not empty

  $query= mysqli_query($sql,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE uname='".$uname."' AND pass='".$pass1."' && memb='?'");
  if(!$query){ die(mysqli_error($sql)); }
  $checkuser= mysqli_num_rows($query);


  if($checkuser != 1) {


   $error = "Username doesn't exist in our database!";
  }

  // Change $login with $query
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $checkpass= $row['pass'];

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
   $checkmemb= $row['memb'];   

   // here i changed $pass1 to $checkpass
   if ($pass1 == $checkpass && $memb == 0){

    setcookie("user", $uname, time()+7200);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $uname;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60 * 60);
    header("Location: pay.php");
    exit();
   } elseif($pass1 == $checkpass && $memb == 1) {
     setcookie("user", $uname, time()+7200);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $uname;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60 * 60);
    header("Location: main.html");
    exit();
   }
  }
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Login']) && isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pass1'])) {
// Here check if all input are sent
```

to:

```
if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pass1'])) {
// Here check if all input are sent
```

Didn't test, this is just a guess from a quick look.
But it seems to be not doing anything because your input check is failing.